# Algorithm that finds the maximum product - Analysis

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have this code which is calculating the largest product you can find using 3 numbers in an array:

```
public static int findMaxProduct(int[] arr) {

        int i=0, j=1, f=2;

        int largest = arr[i]*arr[j]*arr[f];
        for(;i<arr.length;) {
            if(largest<arr[i]*arr[j]*arr[f])
                largest = arr[i]*arr[j]*arr[f];

            if(i==arr.length-3)
                return largest;

            if(f==arr.length-1 && j == arr.length - 2) {
                i++;
                j=i+1;
            }
            if( f==arr.length-1 && j != arr.length-2) 
                f = j+1;

            if(f<arr.length-1)
                f++;
            if(f==arr.length -1 && j < arr.length -2)
                j++;




        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Now, I am not sure of what complexity it is, as we increment `i` if only a condition is met, and we don't know where it's going to execute `i++` . I would appreciate if you help me find the complexity! (Time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You test all the triplets. There are about `n^3` of them. Therefore the complexity is `O(n^3)`.